# NGram and EdgeNGram filters in address typeahead/search

Tags: solr

I have a custom field type:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_pre" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

A database table of addresses that index the full address as text to my SOLR instance, for example:

```
123 W Washington, Some Place, Some State 12345
```

And a typeahead input box which returns search results that closest match the value currently being typed by the user.

**My problem is that for addresses like the example one above, typing "W" or "West" or "W." does not return the above address based on my custom field type.**

I'm not sure if/how possible it is to customize the filters on my field type to accomplish this.  I dont need to support "west" or "w." inputs, I do need to be able to get a proper result by typing "123 W Was" and getting the above example address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the NgramFilterFactory with the WhitespaceTokenizer, you will get ngrams for each token. Using KeywordTokenizerFactory you might get something more like what you want, because it creates ngram tokens from the entire string field rather than individual words. This way it also works across spaces.

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_pre" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll check this out now and see how it goes and give you the checkmark if it fixes my issue :)